# Laravel Sendgrid unsubscribe link

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

I'm unable to attach a group unsubscribe link to my emails using Laravel and Sendgrid. [Sendgrid says](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/group-unsubscribes#group-unsubscribe-substitution-tag),

> When using our ASM Global or Group Unsubscribe tags, you must pass an unsubscribe group in your API or X-SMTPAPI request for the unsubscribe link to populate.

Including an ASM suppression unsubscribe group looks simple according to [Sendgrid's docs](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/building-an-x-smtpapi-header#suppression-groups).

Here's my header code following this [recent demo](https://blakey.co/blog/sendgrid-custom-headers-with-laravel-mail):

```
$header = '{
  "asm_group_id": 23332
}';

$this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use ($header) {
  $message->getHeaders()
  ->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', $header);
});
```

In the email HTML itself I placed `<%asm_group_unsubscribe_url%>` according to this [Sendgrid doc](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260806604209-Unsubscribe-Methods).

Note: A very similar version of this used to work a few years ago but it longer does. This [Github thread](https://github.com/mautic/mautic/issues/10688#issuecomment-995239348) says X-STMPAPI isn't recognized, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: To my knowledge `X-SMTPAPI` headers still work at SendGrid, so I don't know what that GitHub thread is talking about. What are you finding happens when you do all of this? Does the email just not have the link? Can you share the relevant part of the template/HTML you are using?

Comment: Correct. The email just doesn't have the link. All that was previously required in the email was the ```<%asm_group_unsubscribe_url%>``` snippet to generate the full `<a>` tag with appropriate unsubscribe `href`. I suspect the issue is with how the header is specified in the PHP, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Are you using Laravel 9? It seems that [the `withSwiftMessage` method has be renamed to `withSymfonyMessage`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#symfony-mailer). Also, is it confusing to have the outer variable `$header` then shadowed by the `use ($header)` and used inside the closure? Do you need the `use` statement there?

Comment: @philnash thanks yes i'm using Laravel 9. I will change to withSymphonyMessage. Hopefully that will do the trick. I'm not sure if I need to use statement. I was under the impression one needed to use `use` when closures were involved to pass the variable inside. Am I not understanding something?

Comment: I am not a PHP expert I'm afraid, just trying to think of things that might be wrong. Can you try without the `use` and see what happens?

Comment: Changing simply to withsymphonymessage in the code didn’t fix the issue. Might you suggest anything else?

Comment: I'm a bit lost with this I'm afraid. Checking with my colleagues to see if anyone else can help.